# Create Query 'has one' relationship in reverse direction GORM

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm, go-gin

I am currently trying to create a new record using GORM and these two models has a one to one relationship with each other. Model1 has 'has one' relationship with Model2. I was thinking if it is possible to create query Model2 instead of Model1 in this case. Here is an example from the docs:

[image]

So in the docs context, is it possible to create query from the CreditCard struct as I want to persist the 'has one' relationship.

Comment: Can you explain more? What is your expectation from the query? what is the input and output of query?

Comment: @AminRashidbeigi Oh I simply wanted to create CreditCard struct instead of creating User with a nested CreditCard in it. Hence 'reverse direction'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it! You can simply just include the foreign key in the struct model when creating it. For example:

```
CreditCard{
    Number: "41111111111111"
    UserID: <include the id here> // make sure the credit card gorm model has UserID foreign key specified
}
db.Create(&CreditCard)
```